# Change class variable after finding

Tags: c++, class, chess

I am currently working on a chess engine in C++, and in the engine, I'm trying to modify a string variable "piece" inside of a class "ChessTile" within another class called "ChessBoard".

Anyways when I use a function to return a class, then modify said class, it doesn't change the source variable, and I was wondering how you do that.

Here is a simple script I wrote to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class child {
private:
    int myVar;

public:
    child(int v) {
        myVar = v;
    }

    int getVar() {
        return myVar;
    }

    int setVar(int Svar) {
        this->myVar = Svar;
        return 0;
    }
};

class parent {
public:
    child baby = child(0);

    child findMyChild(int var) {
        if (var == 1) {
            return baby;
        }
    }
};

parent DAD;

int main() {
    std::cout << DAD.findMyChild(1).getVar() << std::endl;
    DAD.findMyChild(1).setVar(50);
    std::cout << DAD.findMyChild(1).getVar() << std::endl;
}
```

The output for this is:

```
0
0
```

But I'm wanting it to be:

```
0
50
```

If necessary, I can also post my chess engine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `findMyChild()` is returning a copy of the `baby` ( function returning  by value), use return by reference instead like so.

```
child& parent::findMyChild(int var) {
    if (var == 1)
    {
       return baby;
    }
    /* other codes */
    return baby; 
}
```

Comment: I figured as much, but wasn't sure how to return the reference. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: What's if `var != 1`? Stands for the question as well. Currently both are UB

Comment: @pergy: Agreed but OP showcasing a toy program, perhaps multiple child objects under parent. Code edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a copy of `child` in `findMyChild`. Therefore, you modify only that copy, not the member itself.

You should return a pointer to the member

```
child* findMyChild(int var) {
    return var == 1
      ? &baby
      : nullptr;
}
```

then dereference it to get/set its value. For example:

```
DAD.findMyChild(1)->setVar(50);
```

Since `findMyChild` can return null pointer in my code you should check its existence before accessing

```
child* c = DAD.findMyChild(1);
if (c) c->setVar(50);
```

Comment: This will dereference a null pointer if the child is not found. It would be better to avoid using raw pointers, e.g. return by reference or throw exception if not found.

Comment: That's true. Should be done some checking. Using reference you should throw, almost the same complexity added in my eyes. That's why I prefer raw pointers in such conditional cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via returning pointer/reference of `child` as stated by another comment or you can do it via an interface in `parent` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define FIRST_CHILD 1
#define CANNOT_FIND_CHILD -1

class child {
private:
    int myVar;

public:
    child(int v) {
        myVar = v;
    }

    int childGetVar() {
        return myVar;
    }

    int childSetVar(int Svar) {
        this->myVar = Svar;
        return 0;
    }
};

class parent {
public:
    child baby = child(0);
    int getVar(int var) {
        if (var == FIRST_CHILD)
            return baby.childGetVar();
        return CANNOT_FIND_CHILD;
    }

    int setVar(int var, int Svar) {
        if (var == FIRST_CHILD)
            baby.childSetVar(Svar);
        return CANNOT_FIND_CHILD;
    }
};

parent DAD;

int main() {
    std::cout << DAD.getVar(FIRST_CHILD) << std::endl;
    DAD.setVar(FIRST_CHILD, 50);
    std::cout << DAD.getVar(FIRST_CHILD) << std::endl;
}
```